# WPF - adorner stays in original position after view transitions

Tags: wpf, position, transition, adorner

I have a control template defined, call it myVal, that is used for validation - this is then used for example in a Style targeting textbox where its Validation.ErrorTemplate is set as

Now say there are a number of such textboxes that sit in a view and that this slides in using TranslateTransform and BeginAnimation.

The result is that the adorner used in the ErrorTemplate doesn't follow the position of the textboxes as the view transitions - instead these stay in the starting position. However, the adorners reposition themselves correctly in relation to the textboxes as soon as I set focus or events such as mouse move.

How can I get the adorners to show in the correct position after the transformation without having to change the focus? Is there a way of delaying the validation until after the transition...or how can I "revalidate" the properties once the animation has finished? I read somewhere about calling invalidatevisual but can't see how I'd do that. Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ideas:

Try adding an AdornerDecorator around the textbox, or around the group of textboxes. This will tell WPF to add another layer for rending adorners. Adding a layer "closer" to the textboxes might help.

If you want to tell the adorner layer to re-render itself, then you can use something like the following code:

```
var al = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(myTextBox);
al.Update();
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, Thanks for your reply, much appreciated. I tried wrapping an AdornerDecorator around the textbox, well I actually tried it around a combobox but I'm guessing it's the same for the textbox, and didn't have any luck. The adorners still appear in their original position. That's what I was going to write until having a closer look and realising that it did indeed fix the problem (I'd only applied it to one out of a screen full of items and failed to locate the one I had changed). Just to be clear, the solution works beautifully. Thanks for all your help Nathan!